# pl.datetime plots as days since epoch or 1970, if formatted - polars and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, python-polars

I'm attempting to port some old reports from Pandas to Polars. I am happy with the data, and am now attempting to plot a few time series. This is working, but I'm finding that matplotlib just doesn't seem to want to cooperate with Polars' `pl.Datetime` types.

When initially populating the dataframe, I am doing this to parse the timestamps:

```python
# using floats so we don't quantize when doing mean() aggregations later
df = df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col("AllocCPUS").cast(pl.Float64),
        pl.col("AllocNodes").cast(pl.Float64),
        pl.col("Start").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%FT%T"),
        pl.col("End").str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%FT%T"),
    ]
)
```

This seems to work correctly. Skipping forward over a bunch of (what should be irrelevant) logic, we come to trying to generate a plot. Here's what one of the dataframes looks like just before calling matplotlib:

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ Start               ┆ AllocCPUS │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64       │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2022-01-26 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0       │
│ 2022-01-29 00:00:00 ┆ 1.0       │
│ 2022-01-31 00:00:00 ┆ 4.0       │
│ 2022-02-01 00:00:00 ┆ 9.0       │
│ 2022-02-02 00:00:00 ┆ 34.0      │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

I attempt to plot this, like so:

```python
## relevant imports from earlier in the project
#
#import polars as pl
#import matplotlib
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8), facecolor='white')
ax_cpu = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax_ram = ax_cpu.twinx()

ax_cpu.set_ylim(ymax=cores_max)
ax_ram.set_ylim(ymax=memory_max)

ax_cpu.set_ylabel('Cores', fontsize=14, color='purple') 
ax_ram.set_ylabel('RAM (GB)', fontsize=14, color='orange')

ax_cpu.plot(binned_df_cpu_all, color='purple', alpha=0.8)
ax_ram.plot(binned_df_ram_all, color='orange', alpha=0.8)

ax_cpu.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
ax_ram.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

plt.title('Total Cores/RAM Allocation\n{start} through {end}'.format(
    start=datestamp_min.date(), end=datestamp_max.date()))
```

This prints the graph as I expect to see, with a correct title (note: dates look correct there!), Y axis ranges, etc. However, across the X axis the dates are formatted "1970-01" and so on. If I drop the two `set_major_formatter()` calls, the dates are simply integers starting from 0, one per day.

[image: image of plot with bad dates]

I've been trying to find an explanation or workaround, but unfortunately all of my searching is only turning up people asking how to initially parse strings into dates in Polars - something I'm past, here. Alternatively, I can occasionally find vague references to a problem with matplotlib and pandas where they had differences between epochs, however I am not using pandas here. Additionally, even if I cast the dtype to a python `datetime.datetime`, or even cast the whole polars dataframe to either a pandas dataframe or a numpy 2d array, the behavior does not change (which I *thought* would rule out an interoperability issue).

I'm at a complete loss as to what is going wrong. I can't imagine I'm running into a bug, here, and I must be doing something wrong? Just in case, however, I want to note that I a have `polars==0.16.7` and `matplotlib==3.7.0`. I am running this within JupyterLab at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself today. I don't understand why, but explicitly passing the datetime series and value series to matplotlib, instead of the dataframe (or numpy array) directly, does the job.

````python
## relevant imports from earlier in the project
#
#import polars as pl
#import matplotlib
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8), facecolor='white')
ax_cpu = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax_ram = ax_cpu.twinx()

ax_cpu.set_ylim(ymax=cores_max)
ax_ram.set_ylim(ymax=memory_max)

ax_cpu.set_ylabel('Cores', fontsize=14, color='purple') 
ax_ram.set_ylabel('RAM (GB)', fontsize=14, color='orange')

cpu_axes_time  = binned_df_cpu_all.get_column("Start")
cpu_axes_value = binned_df_cpu_all.get_column("AllocCPUS")
ram_axes_time  = binned_df_ram_all.get_column("Start")
ram_axes_value = binned_df_ram_all.get_column("ReqMem")

ax_cpu.plot(cpu_axes_time, cpu_axes_value, color='purple', alpha=0.8)
ax_ram.plot(ram_axes_time, ram_axes_value, color='orange', alpha=0.8)

plt.title('Total Cores/RAM Allocation\n{start} through {end}'.format(
    start=datestamp_min.date(), end=datestamp_max.date()))

# optional, rotates them a bit nicely
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```
````